# How can I use dill instead of pickle with load_balanced_view

Tags: parallel-processing, ipython, dill

I know I can make IPython parallel use dill instead of pickle with a direct view using

```
c = Client()
dv = c[:]
dv.use_dill()
```

But how can I enable it with `dv.load_balanced_view()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can call `use_dill` on a direct view and then use a load-balanced view:

```
c = Client()
c.direct_view().use_dill()
v = c.load_balanced_view()
...
```

From the [DirectView.use_dill](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.parallel.client.view.html#IPython.parallel.client.view.DirectView.use_dill) documentation:

> This calls IPython.utils.pickleutil.use_dill() here and on each
>   engine.